# Enumerating over a input

Tags: python

Basically so my objective for doing this was, to make it easier for writing an if statement after enumerate to see if the input string contains any numbers in the middle of the string.. if it does than to return True so that it is invalid... which could be a couple issues with doing this in the main function but hopefully someone can let me know if I am going about this a "smart" way, and how to actually implement it correctly into the main function.

```
import string


def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    return_val = exclusions(plate)
    checkplate = platecheck(plate)

    if return_val:
        print("Invalid")
    else:
        print(checkplate)
        print("Valid")


def exclusions(s):
    new_string = s.translate(
        str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    if len(new_string) < len(s):
        print("Please do not use punctuation")
        return True
    elif 2 <= len(new_string) <= 6:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def platecheck(s):
    for i, l in (enumerate(s, 1)): 
        print(l, i) # Some sort of if statement here


main()
```

Everything currently works as far as the the exclusions function, making sure there is no punctuation, and making sure the input is  between 2 to 6 characters.

Example of input/output if working correctly:

Input:

```
t33st
```

Output:

```
Numbers only allowed at the end of the plate
Invalid
```

Current Output:

```
t 1
3 2
3 3
s 4
t 5
None
Valid
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return False` after the punctuation message?

Comment: It looks like `exclusions` returns `True` if _there are_ violations of the rules outlined.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's working in the opposite manner know it looks confusing because invalid is first in the if-statement in the main function, so it says invalid if there is punctuation.

Comment: Really if there are issues with that I'll try and deal with them after I am just super confused on how to pick numbers out of the middle of a string, I was going to attempt using enumerate as I thought that would be easier but not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to determine if the tail is digits is to find the first digit and call `isdigit` on the remainder of the string:

```
def platecheck(s):
    first = next(i for i, c in enumerate(s), len(s))
    return not s[first:].isdigit()
```

A more general tool for checking text patterns is called [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html), which python implements via the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```
plate_pattern = re.compile('\D*\d*')
def platecheck(s):
    return not plate_pattern.fullmatch(s)
```

You can write `exclusions` more elegantly as

```
def exclusions(s):
    if any(c in string.punctuation for c in s):
        print("Please do not use punctuation")
        return True
    return len(s) > 6 or len(s) < 2
```

Since True indicates a problem, you should combine your functions with `or`:

```
return_val = exclusions(plate) or platecheck(plate)
```

More generally, if you have a list of functions, you can use `any`, which short-circuits just like `or`:

```
tests = [exclusions, platecheck]
invalid = any(test(plate) for test in tests)
```

Comment: Okay I like the regular expressions way, I was also getting some sort of error with the first method you posted. I'll have to look more into regular expressions, but so yes that works and will print back True, should I had an elif statement into my main function? EDIT: Okay, yes just added an elif statement to the main function and was able to bring the other function in thank you.

Comment: oooh okay awesome I see, I didn't even know I could combine functions like that! ( Which assume I never really tried )

Comment: @Blue. Updated some more. Enjoy. Everything in python is an object, and everything has a boolean value

Comment: Ooooooohhh, I see okay if I have a list of functions then I can use any.. I haven't read into any at all yet so that is completely new to me - Thanks a ton and also thanks for breaking it down a little for me definitely introduced some new things to me and thanks for telling me what is "generally" used.

Comment: Not sure if you will reply to this message, but if I need to make sure that 0 is not the first number the user inputs at the end of the string, any general uses for doing something simple like that?

Comment: @Blue. Take a look at the enumeration. You can make it return both the index and the character. Then you can check for zeros